# Page number in Odoo 13

Tags: python, pdf, report, wkhtmltopdf, qweb

I'd like to get page number in my report body in Odoo 13 BUT NOT IN THE FOOTER like we can see all over the web.

I tried:

```
<span class="page"/> / <span class="topage"/>
```

But got:

[image]

Please help me!
Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get total pages in wkhtmltopdf body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784943/how-do-i-get-total-pages-in-wkhtmltopdf-body)

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem within Odoo (or Flectra) but in wkhtmltopdf that does not support this feature.
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1889